# JS react manage dark mode ternary

Tags: react-native

How to choose the dark mode properly?

```
  {isDarkMode ? <ImageBackground source={require('../Images/bgndDark/bgGradient.png')} style={styles.container}>
    <Charter isDarkMode />
  </ImageBackground > : <Charter isDarkMode={false} />
  }
```

Just feels wrong to duplicate "Charter"?

Answer (score 1):

You can store `Charter` and use that instead.

```
const children = () => <Charter isDarkMode />;

if (isDarkMode)
    return (
        <ImageBackground
            {...{ children }}
            source={require("../Images/bgndDark/bgGradient.png")}
            style={styles.container}
        />
    );
return children;
```